# Get remaining dataframe after subsetting

Tags: dataframe, select, julia, subset, sample

Here Alphabets are IDs.

```
data=DataFrame(["A" 2 3 4; "B" 1 2 3;"C" 2 1 2;"D" 2 4 9],:auto)

4 rows × 4 columns
x1  x2  x3  x4
Any Any Any Any
1   A   2   3   4
2   B   1   2   3
3   C   2   1   2
4   D   2   4   9
```

Suppose my sampled data has;

```
2 rows × 4 columns
x1  x2  x3  x4
Any Any Any Any
1   D   2   4   9
2   A   2   3   4
```

I want to get **remaining data that excludes rows with D and A.**
I can get it simply by selecting columns 2 and 3. But I need other method for large datasets.

Answer (score 3):

> But I need other method for large datasets.

The size of the data set does not matter here. If you have any row selector, call it `rows` that you used to select rows with `"D"` and `"A"` then just use `Not(rows)` selector to select all the remaining rows.

If you do not have a row selector that you used to create a first data frame here is an efficient pattern that performs the required selection:

```
data[(!in(Set(["A", "D"]))).(data.x2), :]
```

If you want something simpler to understand but less efficient you can use:

```
data[[!(v in ["A", "D"]) for v in df.x2], :]
```

As a side comment (since you want to work with large data sets) - it is more efficient to have your columns have element type more specific than `Any`. You can do column type narrowing by writing `data = identity.(data)`.

If something from what I have written above would be not clear please ask in the comment for explanation.